# Strategies to link RXJS operations in ngrx/effects to call Firebase for different operations before calling an Action

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, observable

I have a situation I do not know how to handle. The situation is to long pull Firebase, get some data as observable back to the ngrx/effects, and then call Firebase again to delete some data and then finally pass in the first Firebase return data to an Action for a reducer to do its thing.

Here is the ngrx/effects code

```
    constructor(private threadsService: ThreadsService, private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {
    
      }
    
      @Effect() newMessages$ = Observable.interval(5000)
        .withLatestFrom(this.store.select("uiState"))
        .map(([any,uiState]) => uiState)
        .do(console.log)
        .filter(uiState => uiState.userId)
        .switchMap(uiState => this.threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId))
        .withLatestFrom(this.store.select("uiState"))
        .do(console.log)
        .switchMap(([messages, uiState]) => this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(messages, uiState.userId))
        .map(messages => new NewMessagesReceivedAction(messages))
```

The first this.threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId) will get the Firebase data I eventually need for NewMessagesReceivedAction(messages). But before I pass in the message observable, I also need to delete MessagesQueuePerUser so the next interval will return empty as the new message is already been pulled. But the above code won't work and has funky result and lots of error:

ERROR #1: without .do(console.log) before the filter, this code

```
.filter(uiState => uiState.userId)
```

will throw an error in WebStorm - Property 'userId' does not exist on type '{}'.)

ERROR #2: these 3 lines just wont work:

```
  // .withLatestFrom(this.store.select("uiState"))
 // .do(console.log)
 // .switchMap(([messages, uiState]) => this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(messages, uiState.userId))
```

The idea of these 3 lines is to continue to pass the message observable down the line, but I also again need the uiState.userId to delete some data in Firebase using this: this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(messages, uiState.userId). But the messages observable pass in the first Firebase list won't go down to the second one.
Here is the threadsService code:

```
  firebaseUpdate(dataToSave) {

    const subject = new Subject();

    this.sdkDb.update(dataToSave)
      .then(
        val => {
          subject.next(val);
          subject.complete();
        },
        err => {
          subject.error(err);
          subject.complete();
        }
      );

    return subject.asObservable();
  }

  loadNewMessagesForUser(uid: string): Observable<Message[]> {

    console.log ("We are pulling the server! uid: " + uid);

    return this.findMessagesForMessageKeys(this.findMessageKeysPreUserUnread(uid));

  }

  findMessagesForMessageKeys(messageKeys$:Observable<string[]>): Observable<Message[]> {
return messageKeys$
  .map(pspp => pspp.map(messageKey => this.db.object('message/' + messageKey)))
  .flatMap(fbojs => Observable.combineLatest(fbojs))
   }

  deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(messages:Observable<Message[]>, uid:string): Observable<Message[]> {

    let dataToSave = {};
    dataToSave['MessagesQueuePerUser/' + uid] = null;
    this.firebaseUpdate(dataToSave);
    return messages;
  }

  findMessageKeysPreUserUnread(uid: string):Observable<string[]> {
    return this.db.list('MessagesQueuePerUser/' + uid)
      .map(getKeys => getKeys.map(p => p.$key));
  }
```

Could anyone point me to the right direction to figure out how to structure and write this right?

## UPDATE to clarify.

Yes I have UiState type. And what I really want is to get the NewMessages from this.threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId). AFTER I get the NewMessages (as it is an observable, async operation), I want to run the delete action (more like a side effect inside a side effect). When I trigger the action NewMessagesReceivedAction(messages), the data should be from this.threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId). Hope this clarify thing a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a UiState type.

This is one way to do it:

```
@Effect() newMessages$ = Observable.interval(5000)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store.select("uiState"))        
    .map(([any,uiState]) => uiState)
    .filter(uiState => uiState.userId)
    .switchMap(uiState => threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId)
      .switchMap(newMessages => threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(newMessages, uiState.userId)
      .map(deletedMessages => newMessages)))
    .map(messages => ({ type:'MESSAGES_RECEIVED', payload: messages }));
```

Working plunker:
https://embed.plnkr.co/BdZOD3XHEXU14GveQUBv/

Comment: Hi @John Hamm. Thank you for the answer. I updated my question to clarify things. Hope that help. The ideal situation is I do NOT need to pass the messages into this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser, so I can simplify the function it as this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(userId). I just don't know how to get the NewMessage from an observable BEFORE. Also, your solution, do I get the userId? You map only the messages, where userId come from as it is belong to switchMap.

Comment: Your solution, there is typescript error: Argument of type 'Message[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<Message[]>'. It is highlight error on the messages in this.threadsService.deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(messages, userId)

Comment: You get the userId from the containing switchMap.  You will notice that the inner ".map(messages..." will have access to any variables passed to any outer maps or observables.  Instead of ending the switchMap after loadNewMessagesForUser, I simply chain another map to the first map instead of ending the switchMap so it can access the userId.

Comment: But your code still won't work as I mentioned earlier. Webstorm says Argument of type 'Message[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<Message[]>'. I think inside the switchMap, your code turn messages into NOT an observable. So it won't pass tho the next deleteMessagesQueuePerUser function which expects an observable and returns an observable. As I mentioned in my UPDATE, I just want the "side" function deleteMessagesQueuePerUser to go delete someone in Firebase using the userId. The messages I need is still from loadNewMessagesForUser(userId). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I used vscode as an editor.  I have a working plunker here you can see it working.  I've updated my answer as well:

https://embed.plnkr.co/BdZOD3XHEXU14GveQUBv/

Comment: Awww, It still won't work on my end. I saw you use switchMap instead of map this time. But the error still is: Argument of type 'Message[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<Message[]>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Message[]'.) The code still try to assign an array to an Obervable.

Comment: Remove the first parameter from your deleteMessagesQueuePerUser method.  You don't need it.  Just return the firebaseUpdate instead:
deleteMessagesQueuePerUser(uid:string): Observable {

    let dataToSave = {};
    dataToSave['MessagesQueuePerUser/' + uid] = null;
    return this.firebaseUpdate(dataToSave);
  }

Comment: Oh sorry. Absolutely! I just did. The code still does not work on my end tho.